# How to use regex in shell with special characters?

Tags: regex, shell

I tried follow but it can't work:

```bash
condition="^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\*\+,;=.]+$"
if [[ $1 =~ condition ]]
then
        echo fine
else
        echo bad
fi
```

It's used to determine whether the first param is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(https?://)?[[:alnum:]_.-]+(\.[[:alnum:]_.-]+)+[][[:alnum:]_.~:/?#@!$&'*+,;=.-]+$
```

This means:

- No non-capturing groups, all `(?:` need to be replaced with `(`
- `\w` might not be supported in all environments, it can be replaced with `[[:alnum:]_]` pattern
- You can't escape special chars inside bracket expressions and `-`, `]` and `^` need to follow "smart placement" rule (`]` should be at the start of the bracket expression and `-` must be at the end).

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/rgWkK0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
url='http://www.blah.com'
condition='^(https?://)?[[:alnum:]_.-]+(\.[[:alnum:]_.-]+)+[][[:alnum:]._~:/?#@!$&'"'"'*+,;=.-]+$'
if [[ "$url" =~ $condition ]]
then
    echo fine
else
    echo bad
fi
```

Output: `fine`

*Note*:

- `$1` in your script should be quoted, `"$1"`
- The `condition` must be prepended with `$`
- Make sure you define the pattern with single quotes to avoid issues with some special chars.

Comment: The only thing I might do differently here would be changing `\.` to `[.]` to be parsed in a manner that's more independent of context.